# Google Place API error while hitting lookUpPlaceID() mehtod of GMSPlacesClient?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, google-places-api

```
 func getPlaceDetails(_ placeId:String){
       placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()

        placesClient?.lookUpPlaceID(placeId) { (place:GMSPlace?, error:Error?) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("Place Id error \(error)")
                return
            }
//            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                self.placeArray.append(place!)
                self.placeTableView.reloadData()

        //    }

        }

    }
```

**Error**

> Place Id error Optional(Error Domain=com.google.places.ErrorDomain
>   Code=-3 "An internal error occurred in the Places API library. If you
>   believe this error represents a bug, please file a report using the
>   instructions on our community and support page
>   (https://developers.google.com/places/support)."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An internal error occurred in the
>   Places API library. If you believe this error represents a bug, please
>   file a report using the instructions on our community and support page
>   (https://developers.google.com/places/support).,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x6080002588a0 {Error
>   Domain=com.google.places.server.ErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x6080002515b0 {Error
>   Domain=com.google.GTLRErrorObjectDomain Code=403 "(Forbidden)"
>   UserInfo={error=Forbidden, GTLRStructuredError=GMSx_GTLRErrorObject
>   0x600000440090: {message:"Forbidden" errors:[1] code:403},
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Forbidden)}}}}})

Comment: Mine working fine. I don't think it is a bug. Might be problem with your developer console API settings, Have you enabled relevant APIs. Enable Google Places API

Comment: also where are you calling this func from?

Comment: YES @RajanMaheshwari

Comment: might be i have crossed 1000 request limit @RajanMaheshwari

Comment: Yes 1000 request for a day is the limit. You will get this type of error in more than 1000 requests per day

Comment: Yes Today it is working

Comment: Thanks for the info. Saved me a lot of time. Will it work if I create a new API key ? @RajanMaheshwari

Comment: I think it might work if you create a separate project and add the bundle Id of your old project while making new key for the newly created project. Not sure..

Comment: Sometimes the issue might be with a placeID. For example i tried this place id -> ChIJSdXURDeXyzsRWybDGetBkKM multiple days from different devices with individual data connections. Still getting error -> domain: @"com.google.places.ErrorDomain" - code: 18446744073709551613